# C++ Array doesn't take negative numbers into account

Tags: arrays

I am trying to write a simple code to get the minimum and the maximum of an array. The problem is that if I choose to put this sequence of values 5 2 -13 5 1. the output is Maximum number is 5 minimum number is 1. why the code is ignoring the negative number? the same thing goes if I put a sequence of negative numbers like -2 -4 -123 -4 5 the maximum number is 5 and minimum is -4

I cant understand why!

```
cout<<"Enter the Value of the Array"<<endl;
cin>>valueOfArray;
cout<<"Enter the Array Elements"<<endl;
for(int i=0; i<valueOfArray;i++)
{
    cin>>ArrayOfNumbers[i];
    minimum=ArrayOfNumbers[0];
    if(ArrayOfNumbers[i]>maximum)
    {
        maximum=ArrayOfNumbers[i];
    }

    else if(ArrayOfNumbers[i]<minimum)
    {
        minimum=ArrayOfNumbers[i];
    }

}
cout<<"the Maximum number is "<<maximum<<endl;
cout<<"The Minimum number is "<<minimum<<endl;
```

Comment: aren't you overriding your minimum each iteration.. minimum=ArrayOfNumbers[0] ...

Comment: What did you discover when you tried to debug the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems, some of which are pointed out in the other answers.

Ultimately, to get proper output, you'll have to initialize your `minimum` and `maximum` vars to their polar opposites outside your array.

```
#include<climits>

long minimum = LONG_MAX;
long maximum = LONG_MIN;

for(int i = 0; i < valueOfArray; i++){
     cin>>ArrayOfNumbers[i];
     if (ArrayOfNumbers[i] > maximum) {
          maximum = ArrayOfNumbers[i];
     } else if (ArrayOfNumbers[i] < minimum) {
          minimum = ArrayOfNumbers[i];
     }
}
```

This solution will ensure that any number in the range LONG_MIN < n < LONG_MAX will register either as a minimum or maximum, as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

your looping logic is little wrong.

maybe this can help

```
minimum=0;
maximum=0;
for(int i=0; i<valueOfArray;i++){
     cin>>ArrayOfNumbers[i];
     if(ArrayOfNumbers[i]>maximum){
          maximum=ArrayOfNumbers[i];
     }

     else if(ArrayOfNumbers[i]<minimum){
          minimum=ArrayOfNumbers[i];
     }
}
```

that happen because everytime you input data, you change your minimum value to your first data.